# Special header with logo and boxes

Tags: header-footer, minipage

I'd like to write lots of procedure to different companies and the header is already fixed. I looks something like that:

[image: I need something like this]

I really know only the basics in LaTex but tried to make a code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pdfgentounicode=1

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0pt}
\vspace*{2.5cm}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.22\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{latex_logo.png}

copany name
\end{center}
\end{minipage}}\hspace{.01\textwidth}%
%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0pt}
\vspace*{2.5cm}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.56\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\textsc{Some text}

\textbf{Some text}

more text

\end{center}
\end{minipage}}\hspace{.01\textwidth}%
%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0pt}
\vspace*{2.5cm}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.22\textwidth}
\begin{center}
Important

{\footnotesize
    \textbf{some information:} ....

    \textbf{last modified: }2017.12.24.

    \textbf{edited by: }xy
}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

My questions:

- Could somebody make this code better? (eg: I used 0pt minipage because I can't make all boxes the same hight...)
- How can I put it in the header? I tried to use fancyhead but it doesn't worked for me (maybe if I can delete the LeftHeader and the RightHeader and change the size of the centered to \textwidth I can do, but it's still a big mess)

Thanks in advance (and happy Christmas)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I would do it using a single `tabularx{\textwidth}` and 3 columns. For the header, you'll have to specify, as an option of geometry, `[headheight=2.5cm]`.

Answer (score 3):

A command like `\begin{minipage}[t][2.5cm][c]{.5\linewidth}...\end{minipage}` will create a `minipage` with the specified height of `2.5cm` (the minipage will be vertically aligned to the `[t]`op and its content to the `[c]`enter).

To place the minipages in the header, you can use `fancyhdr` but you need to be very careful to avoid having blank lines inside `\lhead{...}`, `\chead{...}` and `\rhead{...}`, because that will generate errors. For example, for the center box:

```
\chead{%
    \fbox{%
        \begin{minipage}[t][2.5cm][c]{.5\linewidth}%
            \begin{center}
                \textsc{Some text}\\
                %
                \textbf{Some text}\\
                %
                more text\\
%               %
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}%
    }% end \fbox
}% end \chead
```

You also need to manually set the header height:

```
\setlength{\headheight}{3cm}
```

[image: header]

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pdfgentounicode=1

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{3cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{%
    \fbox{%
        \begin{minipage}[t][2.5cm][c]{.22\linewidth}%
            \begin{center}              
                %               \includegraphics[width=2cm]{latex_logo.png}             
                company name
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}%
    }% end \fbox
}% end \lhead

\chead{%
    \fbox{%
        \begin{minipage}[t][2.5cm][c]{.5\linewidth}%
            \begin{center}
                \textsc{Some text}\\
                %
                \textbf{Some text}\\
                %
                more text\\
%               %
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}%
    }% end \fbox
}% end \chead

\rhead{%
    \fbox{%
        \begin{minipage}[t][2.5cm][c]{.22\linewidth}%
            \begin{center}
                Important\\
                %
                {\footnotesize
                    \textbf{some information:} ....\\
                %
                \textbf{last modified: }2017.12.24.\\
                %
                \textbf{edited by: }xy
                        }
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}%
    }% end \fbox
}% end \rhead

\begin{document}
Document body starts here
\end{document}
```